# Visual Studio 2019 Team Explorer Another Browser for Builds

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 Team Explorer for Builds opens builds in external browser.

How can I make it open in Another browser than default?

I want open in it in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can only the browser in one place – the browser you set to launch when debugging web apps.

Anywhere that does not use that setting will use the default browser.

(Personally I just navigate within the Azure DevOps web site – reviewing PRs means I just keep the key projects open!)

Comment: I don't even have WebApps installed. Weird